# How can i add multi column bootstrap menu in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I want to a add 3 column bootstrap menu in WordPress, but i am unable to do this. I have tried a lot, but the sub menus and the columns are not not shows. can any one please help me.

Here is my bootstrap code.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>">
            <img alt="Brand" src="img/is-logo.png">
          </a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Information <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-airplane"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Airlines</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-github"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Animal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-apple"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp;Apple</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Bangladesh"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
                           Bangladesh
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-twitter"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Birds</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-droplet"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Blood</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-git-cat"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Cat</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_China"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span><span class="path4"></span><span class="path5"></span><span class="path6"></span><span class="path7"></span><span class="path8"></span><span class="path9"></span><span class="path10"></span><span class="path11"></span><span class="path12"></span><span class="path13"></span><span class="path14"></span><span class="path15"></span><span class="path16"></span><span class="path17"></span><span class="path18"></span><span class="path19"></span><span class="path20"></span><span class="path21"></span><span class="path22"></span><span class="path23"></span></span>
                           China
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Denmark">
                            <span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span>
                            </span>Denmark
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-library"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Education</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-airplane"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Airlines</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-github"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Animal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-apple"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp;Apple</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Bangladesh"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
                           Bangladesh
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-twitter"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Birds</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-droplet"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Blood</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-git-cat"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Cat</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_China"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span><span class="path4"></span><span class="path5"></span><span class="path6"></span><span class="path7"></span><span class="path8"></span><span class="path9"></span><span class="path10"></span><span class="path11"></span><span class="path12"></span><span class="path13"></span><span class="path14"></span><span class="path15"></span><span class="path16"></span><span class="path17"></span><span class="path18"></span><span class="path19"></span><span class="path20"></span><span class="path21"></span><span class="path22"></span><span class="path23"></span></span>
                           China
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Denmark">
                            <span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span>
                            </span>Denmark
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-library"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Education</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-airplane"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Airlines</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-github"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Animal</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-apple"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp;Apple</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Bangladesh"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span></span>
                           Bangladesh
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-twitter"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Birds</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-droplet"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Blood</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-git-cat"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Cat</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_China"><span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span><span class="path4"></span><span class="path5"></span><span class="path6"></span><span class="path7"></span><span class="path8"></span><span class="path9"></span><span class="path10"></span><span class="path11"></span><span class="path12"></span><span class="path13"></span><span class="path14"></span><span class="path15"></span><span class="path16"></span><span class="path17"></span><span class="path18"></span><span class="path19"></span><span class="path20"></span><span class="path21"></span><span class="path22"></span><span class="path23"></span></span>
                           China
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <a href="#">
                          <span class="icon-Flag_of_Denmark">
                            <span class="path1"></span><span class="path2"></span><span class="path3"></span>
                            </span>Denmark
                        </a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#"><span class="icon-library"></span>&nbsp; &nbsp; Education</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

dropdown menus wont work noramly in the wordpress so use [Walker Class](https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) that will make them work

Comment: Thank You, i am trying with walkers, it just mass up everything, some times it shows the menu, but not with three column,
can you please help me. 
Thank You.

Comment: One more thing where i have to use the class 'multi-column-dropdown'.
Because  'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
then, where should i put that class 'multi-column-dropdown'.

hope you will understand.
Thank You